# What does "the mind" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I use this link but I can't decide which one to use: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mind_1?q=mind

> Defining culture as “the collective programming of the **mind** that distinguishes the members of one human group from another”(p. 21), Hofstede focused particularly on work-related values.The heart of his book is a survey of a large U.S. multinational company’s employees.

Source, a review of : [Reframing Organisations](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=Defining+culture+as%E2%80%9Cthe+collective+programming+of+the+mind+that+distinguishes+the+members+of+one+human+group+from+another%E2%80%9D(p.+21),+Hofstede+focused+particularly+on+work-related+values.+The+heart+of+his+book+is+a+survey+of+a+large+U.S.+multinational+company%E2%80%99s+employees.&source=bl&ots=oxN1BeAj1Q&sig=ACfU3U1xe1ZGQb5vNE3Cs3-ZVajkmKSxtg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif8IOotdvhAhWFPXAKHfgVCHIQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Defining%20culture%20as%E2%80%9Cthe%20collective%20programming%20of%20the%20mind%20that%20distinguishes%20the%20members%20of%20one%20human%20group%20from%20another%E2%80%9D(p.%2021)%2C%20Hofstede%20focused%20particularly%20on%20work-related%20values.%20The%20heart%20of%20his%20book%20is%20a%20survey%20of%20a%20large%20U.S.%20multinational%20company%E2%80%99s%20employees.&f=false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here **mind** means the brain which controls all your feelings, emotions, habits etc.

He defines culture as something that influences your brain(i.e. you emotions, feelings, habits) and this distinguishes one group from the other.